# Datagrid attach rowloading event to all datagrids in project

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to attach a particular `RowLoading` event to all `DataGrid` in all datagrids in the project (there are around 20 of them). The event is this:

```
private void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
    }
```

I want to attach the event in startup of the project like this:
 
            `EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(DataGrid), DataGrid.LoadingRowEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(dataGrid_LoadingRow));`

Unfortunately the `DataGrid.LoadingRowEvent` gives an error since there is no event with DataGrid class with that name present. However there is an event with that name and I can manually add the event for each grid.
Is there any way to do this without creating a custom control or changing the DataGrid declaration everywhere it has been used?

Answer (score 1):

The `LoadingRow` event is not implemented as a routed event in WPF so you can't use the trick with `EventManager`. 
You don't need a custom control. Just derive the `DataGrid` class:

```
class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnLoadingRow(DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoadingRow(e);
    }
}
```

So in using the `MyDataGrid` instead of `DataGrid` class you have full control over what happens in `OnLoadingRow`.

Comment: I think so. You could find all DataGrid instances by reflection and access their event handlers. But that would be a very dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case your question is only about the row index in the header, you wouldn't need to handle the `LoadingRow` event. Instead, you may use a binding to the [AlternationIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex.aspx) property:

```
<DataGrid AlternationCount="2147483647" ...>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Header"
                Value="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                Converter={StaticResource RowIndexConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

You may put this in a default `DataGrid` style, so that it automatically applies to all DataGrid instances:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2147483647"/>
    <Setter Property="RowStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Header"
                    Value="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                    Converter={StaticResource RowIndexConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The binding converter would look like this:

```
public class RowIndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}", (int)value + 1);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```